# Review one-by-one feature?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, broken-code

I am writing a library. It is mostly ready, but there are known bugs and ToDo stuff (including for example missing `const` specifiers for member functions which do not need to modify the object) and unittests are not yet done.

I want to ask community opinion on some features.

Should I produce one question for the entire list of questionable features of the entire library? Or should I ask one-by-one feature?

If so, should I first finish the library before asking questions or should I ask now when it yet has known serious deficiencies?

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is, if you know that your code has deficiencies that need to be fixed, then it is [not ready to be reviewed here](/a/5781/9357).

In general, we expect questions to have [no known bugs](/q/9044/9357).  It might be OK to declare known issues, but only if you consider them to be insignificant or irrelevant for your intended deployment.  Otherwise, you should fix those issues before asking for a review.

Asking for advice about features that have not yet been implemented is strictly [off-topic](/help/on-topic) for Code Review, because incomplete code would not be "working correctly as intended".

In summary, you should finish your project, make the code as good as you can possibly make it, and ensure that it works to your satisfaction, before posting it here for a review.

Comment: If there are some specific features that are stand-alone though, then it should be fine to ask about those without having the entire library finished.